# How to customize formatting of destructured types in Serilog

Tags: c#, .net, serilog

The code below produces the output: `[2021-09-05 INFO] Created a customer: Customer {Name="Jack"}`.

I have two questions. First, is it possible to remove the space between `Customer` and `{Name="Jack"}`? Second, is it possible to remove the double quotes around `"Jack"`.

Thanks for any help!

```
class Program
{
    public class Customer
    {
        public string Name { get; init; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var customer = new Customer {Name = "Jack"};
        var logger = new LoggerConfiguration().WriteTo.Console(outputTemplate:
            "[{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd} {Level:u4}] {Message:l}{NewLine}").CreateLogger();
        logger.Information("Created a customer: {@Customer}", customer);
    }
}
```

Comment: the customer object is serialized into json...jack is a string...that is why its quoted...without the quotes it would be invalid json

Comment: @Ctznkane525 That's not the case here and it's not valid JSON... The format specified in the output template is `l` (literal) and the text formatter uses quotes to represent strings. Valid JSON would be `{"Name" : "Jack"}` instead of `{Name = "Jack"}` very different...

Comment: you're right my bad

Answer (score 3):

The customization of how data gets rendered depends on the sink you're using as it's up to the sink to provide you a way to do that.

In the case of the [Console sink](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-console/), which is the one you're using, there's nothing out-of-the-box that would allow you to customize the console output in that way, but it does allow you to provide a custom `ITextFormatter` so you can implement your own version of the [`OutputTemplateRenderer`](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-console/blob/v4.0.0/src/Serilog.Sinks.Console/Sinks/SystemConsole/Output/OutputTemplateRenderer.cs), the formatter used by the Console sink, and format the output the way you want it.

Other examples of formatters are the ([`CompactJsonFormatter.cs`](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-formatting-compact/blob/dev/src/Serilog.Formatting.Compact/Formatting/Compact/RenderedCompactJsonFormatter.cs) and the [`RenderedCompactJsonFormatter.cs`](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-formatting-compact/blob/dev/src/Serilog.Formatting.Compact/Formatting/Compact/RenderedCompactJsonFormatter.cs)).

> Documentation:
> https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Formatting-Output

You might also be interested in using an [`ExpressionTemplate`](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Formatting-Output#flexible-formatting-with-expressiontemplate) from [`Serilog.Expressions`](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-expressions)

Comment: Thanks for this. I'll try to implement `ITextFormatter`.